# Heat pump hvac system - can blower motor and its electronic module be replaced separately?

Tags: fans, motor

I am struggling locating a replacement fan motor for my home heat pump system.

Current motor is a GE ECM motor
Model 5SME39HL 0477
CPN HD44AE132
1/2 HP, 1 phase, 60 hz, 120/240 v
0-1400 RPM

Module
GE ECM 2.3, CN03
02HR07

[image: Fan Motor Assy]

I prefer a direct drop in replacment if possible but am having a hard time locating one.
A few questions

1. Do I have to replace both the motor and module at the same time as a set or can I replace one or the other independently?  I believe the motor is OK, no burnt windings and bearings look good, but I am unsure.
2. Can I replace with a different motor assembly and if so what would be a good replacement?
3. If I replace with a different motor assembly, do I have to change the board?

Thanks for any help you can provide, its hot, I have small children and would like to save the labor cost I've been quoted.
Many thanks for your time and help,
Josh

Comment: I'd suggest hitting a store that supplies wholesale parts to the HVAC trade and asking them if they could look up a direct replacement. Or ask the manufacturer . You probably wouldn't be the first to ask them that question.

Comment: That's a recent (2000s) motor, judging by the design language on the labeling. The heat pump or air handler manufacturer will surely tell you exactly what to use and/or will sell you a replacement item they themselves certify as correct.

Comment: Do you know which is bad for sure? This could get interesting in a parts chasing game.

Comment: I took the motor and moduel off and the motor ohmed out and was good to ground, I have 240 v at the motor. A buddy of mine has a cable to test the model, getting that tommarow to confirm the moduel is bad, if it is can i replace the moduel alone. I mean I know I can but is there any risk?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're trying very hard.

https://www.google.com/search?q=genteq+hd44ae132

Comment: I've only been able to find one exact match from united hvac motors but the moduel number is slightly differnt, do you know what kind of issues that would cause? Plan to call them in the morning when they open.